# HTTPPost2 replaces + symbol with a blank space if we use it in an email address

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

In one cloud page where I am using AMPScript to make a HTTPPost2 call to another cloud page and try to retrieve values using SSJS like this:

```
var email = Request.GetFormField('emailaddress');
```

If `emailaddress` contains `+` , it is replacing it with a space.

Example:
`test+test@gmail.com`  will result in `test test@gmail.com` in the second cloud page.

Why is HTTPPost2 replacing `+` with a blank space?  Is there any other alternative approach for this or any other suggestions?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3):

This is a design of how HTTP encodes characters in the URL. Spaces are encoded as plus signs, and plus signs are subsequently decoded as spaces. Since you didn't encode the email correctly, it was interpreted incorrectly. In AmpScript, make sure you use [UrlEncode](https://ampscript.guide/urlencode/) to properly encode URL parameters. In fact, you should always do this for any parameter, unless you find it causes you problems.

Comment: Thanks alot for your quick response and support